# If $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, then show that the circumcenters of triangles $ABC$ and $ADC$ are at the same distance from AC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> $ABCD$ is a parallelogram. Prove that the circumcenters of triangles $ABC$ and $ADC$ are at the same distance from $AC$.

I understand that $ABC$ and $ADC$ are congruent. However, I'm not sure how that will help in the proof.

Hint?

Comment: Rotate by 180 degrees about the centre of ABCD (i.e., the mid-point of AC).

Comment: What is the definition of "circumcentre"? What can you work from there? I mean, try to work from your data, towards a solution, don't try to guess midway (but keep in mind whatever you have noticed)

Comment: Hint: in a diamond, the diagonals are perpendicular bisectors of one-another.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Hint#1:- Will $2\alpha = 2\alpha'?$

Hint#2:- The line of centers will perendicularly bisect the common chord.